# Send credentials in preflighted request (CORS)

Tags: ajax, authentication, http-headers, request, cors

I have to make CORS with content type JSON. This makes the browser send first an OPTIONS request, specifying origin and so on. Then the server should answer with allowed domains, methods, etc. If this goes well, the browser sends the actual request.

My problem is that the server needs authentication for the actual request but ALSO for the OPTIONS request. But the browser doesn't send the authentication headers with the OPTIONS request.

I'm using JQuery and the ajax() function. I tried adding "withCredentials: true", and add the Authorization header, but this not affect the OPTIONS request, it still doesn't send any credentials.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preflight request is only meant to verify if the CORS request itself is allowed. Therefore, cookies are never included in the preflight request. You'd have to validate the user during the actual request.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm also validating during the actual request. But I have to turn off validation for OPTIONS then.

Comment: In a 2-way SSL configuration, doesn't this present a security risk?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Chrome will send the cookies w/ the preflight request if withCredentials=true whereas Firefox will not. Sounds like they've implemented the spec differently.