# Ajax jquery across subdomain - OPTIONS request with 403 Forbidden error

Tags: jquery, cross-domain, authorization, preflight

We have sites hosted on 2 subdomains : http://site1.mydomain.com and http://site2.mydomain.com
and both require Http Authorization to access it for security reasons.

site1 has a link to allow users to Login which opens up a jquery popup for users to provide credentials. After successful POST on submit user can visit site2.

Before the POST, browser makes a OPTION request (Preflight) call which ends up with 403 Forbidden error. 
The issue is as both the site require Basic authorization the OPTION request never reaches the server to add response headers back.

The following are added using a Java servlet filter when the request Method is OPTIONS:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: origin,

Access-Control-Allow-Method: GET, POST, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type

Is there a way we can pass the Authorization credentials through jquery Ajax on PreFlight (OPTIONS) request for it to hit the above Java filter?

I have already tried sending it using headers{'Authorization': 'Basic XXXXX'} but doesnt seem to be working.
Or is there any alternative approach to handle this using Apache?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like cookies and authentication details are never sent for OPTIONS request. Look at answer to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103081/send-credentials-in-preflighted-request-cors)